# How to get corresponding value of key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var getValuesArray = [];
var setValuesArray = [];


function SetValueJson(key, value, scormVersion, methodCalled)
{
   if (key1 != null) {
     var obj = {
      key: key1,
     value: value1
   }
   setValuesArray.push(obj);
   alert("pushing the key as: " + setValuesArray[key] + " and value as: " + setValuesArray[key].value); //not shure how te reference it?
   return value;
}
```

and:

```
function GetValueJson(key, scormVersion, methodCalled) {
   //I will get to this later, want to get the array right first

}
```

How do I reference the array?alert("pushing the key as: " + setValuesArray[key] + " and value as: " + setValuesArray[key].value); is not correct..

thanks

Comment: missing a } somewhere in the first code block too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this basically depends on what you want to do with this data structure.

If keeping these keys and values sequentially and their order is important than you would *need* to store them in an `array`.

If you only need to look up the values based on keys, then a simple `object` would do just fine.

Lets say you need to maintain the order of the key-value data as it comes in, and you're using an array for that, then you have two options:

1. Keep the actual key-value store inside an `object`. For the order, maintain a separate array only keeping the keys. Here's what it should look like somewhat

   ```
   var keyValueStore = {},
       keyOrderStore = [];

   function store(key, value) {
       keyValueStore[key] = value;
       keyOrderStore.push(key);          
   }

   function getValueByIndex(index) {
       // do some bounds checking ofcourse :)
       return keyValueStore[keyOrderStore[index]];
   }

   function getValue(key) {
       return keyValueStore[key];
   }
   ```
2. This is in my opinion a better option. However, if you don't want to maintain and sync two separate data structures, you can use this:

   ```
   var storage = [];

   function store(key, value) {
       storage.push({
           key: key,
           value: value
       });
   }

   function getAtIndex(index) {
       return storage[index].value;
   }

   function getValue(key) {
       for (var i = storage.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
           var obj = storage[i];
           if (obj.key === key) return obj.value;
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thanks option 2 above is what I want, only to look up values when I have a key.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `Object` instead of `Array`.

Modified code

```
var setValuesArray = {};

function SetValueJson(key, value, scormVersion, methodCalled)
{
    setValuesArray[key]= value;
```

alert("pushing the key as: " + key + " and value as: " + value); 
        return value;
    }

```
function GetValueJson(key, scormVersion, methodCalled) {
          return setValuesArray[key]; // will return 'undefined' if key is not present.
}
```